# From Gatwick airport to central London by bus

Tags: london, airport-transfer, buses, lgw

During short visit to London.

Is it possible to go from Gatwick airport to central London (Chiswell street ) by bus on Sunday morning at 10am?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use a bus for the whole way? Train+Bus is likely to be much quicker

Comment: I just wanted to see the city as mush as I can :)
But if using bus Only will waste a lot of time , any other suggestions will be appreciated .

Comment: @MohamedMosaad as per the link in my answer (tfl.gov.uk), you can enter in whatever method you'd like to find the route to anywhere in the greater London area.  I'd recommend the faster overground trains to Victoria or change at Clapham Junction to Waterloo, and go exploring from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, yes, although I recommend the trains, they're far more convenient.

However, if you do want a bus, you could either take a coach into Victoria Station with National Express or [EasyJet's buses](http://www.easybus.com/en/).

The trains are a LOT faster as well.

By bus, it'll take about 3 hours.

[If you start at 10:00am](http://tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/results?IsAsync=true&JpType=publictransport&From=Gatwick%20Airport&FromGeolocation=&ToGeolocation=&ViaGeolocation=&To=Chiswell%20Street%2C%20City%20of%20London&ToId=51.52086734541%2C-0.09081866892&TimeIs=departing&Date=20150118&Time=1000&Via=&NationalSearch=false&JourneyPreference=leasttime&Mode=bus&AccessibilityPreference=norequirements&WalkingSpeed=average&MaxWalkingMinutes=40&CyclePreference=AllTheWay&SavePreferences=false&FromId=1001114):

> 10 mins walking - Walk to Gatwick Airport, A23 South Terminal
>
> 23 mins bus    - 420 bus to Redhill Bus Station
>
> 41 mins   bus - 405 bus to Whitgift Centre
>
> 1 hr 0 min bus - 468 bus to Elephant & Castle Station
>
> 18 mins   bus - 35 bus to Liverpool Street Station
>
> 15 mins   walking - Walk to 34 Chiswell Street, City
>
> Arrival time: 13:10

If you're prepared to take other forms of transport, [it's only about 1 hour and 15 minutes](http://tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/results?IsAsync=true&JpType=publictransport&From=Gatwick+Airport&FromGeolocation=&ToGeolocation=&ViaGeolocation=&To=Chiswell+Street%2C+City+of+London&TimeIs=departing&Date=20150118&Time=1000&Via=&NationalSearch=false&JourneyPreference=leasttime&Mode=tube&Mode=bus&Mode=dlr&Mode=river-bus&Mode=tram&Mode=cable-car&Mode=overground&Mode=national-rail&Mode=coach&AccessibilityPreference=norequirements&WalkingSpeed=average&MaxWalkingMinutes=40&CyclePreference=AllTheWay&SavePreferences=false&FromId=1001114&ToId=51.52086734541%2C-0.09081866892)

Comment: Another good option. Really if it's bus he wants, it'll be the 3 hour option I guess, but if he's prepared to pay a few pounds, other options are faster.

Comment: Erm, when he said "bus", I doubt he meant "strictly local TFL buses only, no coaches". Seems more likely he meant "scheduled buses, coaches etc". With all those changes, local buses wouldn't even be cheaper than coaches.

Answer (score 4):

Using the TFL route planner on http://tfl.gov.uk going from Gatwick Airport to Barbican (which is the nearest underground station) and only allowing buses and coaches and leaving on Sunday the 18th at 10am it suggests:

> Depart 10:05
>
> 5 mins    : Walk to Gatwick Airport, South Terminal Bus Station #nrc
>
> 1 hr 10 mins: Express bus ESB3 to Waterloo Station / York Road
>
> 11 mins   : RV1 bus to Waterloo Bridge / South Bank
>
> 15 mins: 4 bus to Barbican station
>
> Arrive: 12.06 - journey time: 2hr 1min

If you were to ignore coaches (which are really just a type of bus), you are given:

> Depart 10:02
>
> 10 mins: Walk to Gatwick Airport, A23 South Terminal
>
> 23 mins: 420 bus to Redhill Bus Station
>
> 41 mins: 405 bus to Whitgift Centre
>
> 1hr 0 mins: 468 bus to Elephant and Castle Station
>
> 5 mins: Walk to Elephant and Castle / London Road
>
> 18 mins: 63 bus or 45 bus to Snow Hill (EC1)
>
> 10 mins: Walk to Barbican (London), Barbican
>
> Arrive: 13:06 - journey time 3hrs 4 mins

Allowing all transport modes gives the following quick route:

> Depart 10:03
>
> 49 mins: Southern train to London Victoria Rail Station
>
> 3mins: Underground Victoria Line to Oxford Circus Underground Station
>
> 5mins: Underground Central line to St Paul's Underground Station
>
> 9mins: Walk to King Edward Street (EC1)
>
> 11mins: 56 bus to Barbican Station