# Transport services from Gatwick to London

Tags: transportation, london, lgw

I would like to travel to London next week but I don’t know exactly how to get from Gatwick airport to London downtown. I was thinking about a transport service like Uber.

I don’t really like to go by train/underground or bus because then I have to change too often. And a cab is probably too expensive. Can anyone give me some information about the situation with transport services?

Comment: Related [can-i-get-from-gatwick-airport-to-london-by-oyster-card](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37598/can-i-get-from-gatwick-airport-to-london-by-oyster-card) and [from-gatwick-airport-to-central-london-by-bus](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42120/from-gatwick-airport-to-central-london-by-bus)

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions asking the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Going by road from Gatwick Airport into central London is always a stressful and time consuming journey.

Depending on your actual destination (there is no single point that classes as "London downtown"), take the train

either

Southern (not the overpriced Gatwick Express) to Victoria, or change at Clapham Junction for Waterloo.

or

Thameslink to Blackfriars / Farringdon / St Pancras.

Comment: I want to go from gatwick to the area arround paddington station with transport Services like uber do you know about the Situation with these transport Services ? Thanks

Comment: @M.Allison You've already asked this question once on this site. It's linked to above.